# Nested Table Expression not working for db2 z/OS

Tags: db2, zos

The following query works when in run it in DB2 LUW.

```
SELECT 
  TEMP1.SINIESTRO, 
  TEMP1.POLIZA
FROM TABLE(VALUES
    ('00000031955190','0107737793'),
    ('00000118659978','0107828212'),
    ('00000118978436','0095878120'),
    ('00000122944473','0106845043')
) TEMP1(SINIESTRO, POLIZA);
```

When I try to use it in DB2 for z/OS, I get the following error:
SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL ",". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: WITHIN CARDINALITY OVER ). SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.24

I have  tried CTE as well.

```
WITH X(foo, bar, baz) AS (
VALUES (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)
) SELECT * FROM X;
```

And I get this error:
SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "X". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: DSN_INLINE_OPT_HINT. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.24

Any idea what should I change to make it work?

Comment: The VALUES statement is not yet available in Db2-for-Z/OS , so replace with a query on sysibm.sysdummy1 or temp table.

Answer (score 1):

The currently shipping versions of Db2-for-Z/OS do not have a VALUES clause like the other Db2 platforms already have.

The Db2-for-Z/OS has a single-row table called `sysibm.sysdummy1` which some people use.

However, if you can reference a temporary table instead of `sysibm.sysdummy1` then the code looks cleaner.

One awkward way to run your statement on Db2 for Z/OS (other ways exist) is with a CTE that unions rows from sysibm.sysdummy1 ,
(use `union all` in the subquery if appropriate):

```
with temp1 (SINIESTRO, POLIZA)
as
(
   select '00000031955190','0107737793' from sysibm.sysdummy1
   union
   select '00000118659978','0107828212' from sysibm.sysdummy1
   union
   select '00000118978436','0095878120' from sysibm.sysdummy1
   union
   select '00000122944473','0106845043' from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
SELECT 
  TEMP1.SINIESTRO, 
  TEMP1.POLIZA
FROM temp1;
```